# Best practices to use logging or print on Python

Tags: python

I see some posts claims to use logging function instead to show debugging message. I know logging provides various message levels like `info`, `debug`..., etc. `info` level should be used when messages is important for user to trace process on runtime. Just like `info` level in logging, `print` uses in the same case. When to use `logging` or `print` for best practice? Thanks!

```
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def process():
    #### "Create a connection" is a critical message for user to know what operation is processing now
    logger.info("Create a connection with ...")
    # or
    print("Create a connection with ...")
```

Comment: This question is, I'm afraid, rather opinion based, but if you're working on something "serious" I'd go with `logging`, particularly because it allows you to do things like *"When running on production, show only `info` and above, when running on a test environment, show `debug` (and above)"* It also provides much wider tools, such as writing to the std outputs AND files AND emails (if you configure it to do so) and you can even configure it for pretty coloring (info in green, warning in yellow, errors in red...) Things like that (it can be more "powerful" than just `print`)

Comment: For best practices check the following [solution](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch13.html#_adding_logging_to_simple_scripts) from Python Cookbook.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on your own little projects, you can go with `print` but in a bigger project environment you really don't want to use `print` statements as it can quickly become confusing. Especially if you don't know where messages are printed out to your `stdout`. The `logging` module gives you a lot of advantage as:

1) There are `Streamformatters` that allow you to standartize output messages (with timestamps for example and username)

2) Multiple `Streamhandlers`. Most of the time, when something goes wrong, you don't only want to print something to the user through the `stdout` but want to keep that data to see later what went wrong.